# How to use selector to get value under DOM using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a html container structure like as

```
<div class='APart'>
 <div class='Main'>
  <input name='MainInput' value='1'>
 </div>
 <div class='Sub'>
  <input name='SubInput' value='2'>
  <input name='SubInput' value='5'>
 </div>
</div>
<div class='APart'>
 <div class='Main'>
  <input name='MainInput' value='3'>
 </div>
 <div class='Sub'>
  <input name='SubInput' value='4'>
  <input name='SubInput' value='6'>
 </div>
</div>
```

and I using Jquery to do foreach and get data

```
$('.APart input[name=MainInput]').each(function(index, element) {
 console.log(this.value)
});
```

now I know how to get MainInput value,next step how to get SubInput value?

this is my expectation result

array[0] = "1,2,5"

array[1] = "3,4,6"

Comment: You have no `.MainPart` anywhere in your HTML.

Comment: @CertainPerformance is Mian .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new class tag on your input dom

```
<div class='APart'>
 <div class='Main'>
  <input class=''MainClass' name='MainInput' value='1'>
 </div>
 <div class='Sub'>
  <input class=''SubClass' name='SubInput' value='2'>
  <input class=''SubClass' name='SubInput' value='5'>
 </div>
</div>
<div class='APart'>
 <div class='Main'>
  <input class=''MainClass' name='MainInput' value='3'>
 </div>
 <div class='Sub'>
  <input class=''SubClass' name='SubInput' value='4'>
  <input class=''SubClass' name='SubInput' value='6'>
 </div>
</div>
```

so next step we can selector class like as

```
$('.APart').each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).children('.Main').find('.MainClass').each(function (i,e){
        console.log($(e).val())
    });
    $(this).children('.Sub').find('.SubClass').each(function (i,e){
        console.log($(e).val())
    });
});
```

This code to do things

1. get every APart Class
2. get APart DOM Data after to find next children class
3. then we find it after just need use selector to find new class group

Comment: thk u . I got it

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant `MainInput`? You can select inputs via there name attribute, then get their value using the following:

```
$('.APart input[name=MainInput]').each(function(index, element) {
    console.log($(element).val());
});
```

---

Have a look at this [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) cheat sheet for more.

Comment: thk you, but I fix problem description.plz reconfirm

Answer (score 1):

first give a class name for what your are accessing input

```
<div class='APart'>
 <div class='Main'>
  <input name='MainInput' value='1' class="getMain">
 </div>
 <div class='Sub'>
  <input name='SubInput' value='2'>
 </div>
 <div class='Main'>
  <input name='MainInput' value='3' class="getMain">
 </div>
 <div class='Sub'>
  <input name='SubInput' value='4'>
 </div>
</div>
```

after you can access with Jquery

```
 $(':input.getMain').each(function(index, element){
var name = element.name;
```

});

[reference](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

//this will give all your vaues

Comment: thk you, but I fix problem description.plz reconfirm

Answer (score 1):

U can use the each function for looping

```
$('.APart input[name="MainInput"]').each(function(){
console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: thk you, but I fix problem description.plz reconfirm